# PHP. Why does date object diff on month reset to 0 after 12 months?

Tags: php, datetime

Today is 2015-07-08.

When I run the following it returns `0`. Should it not return `12`? The date is 12 months ago. Similarly if `$date='2014-06-03'` it returns `1`. Should it not be `13`? All dates within the last 12 months are calculated correctly.

```
 $date = '2014-07-03';
 $datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-01', strtotime($date)));
 $datetime2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));      
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 $months_ago = $interval->format('%m');
 echo "\n".$months_ago;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is `1 Year` AND `0 Months` ago, not just 12 Months ago. If you were to see the year too you'd get that.

> Note:
>
> The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry over points in time strings nor in date segments. This is expected because it is not possible to overflow values like "32 days" which could be interpreted as anything from "1 month and 4 days" to "1 month and 1 day".

You can use `%a` for the total number of days but i can't find a marker for total number of months.

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)**

Comment: Thanks. That explains it.

Comment: `but i can't find a marker for total number of months`: there isn't one, you should calculate it: `years * 12 + months`.