# DateTime::diff unexpected results

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have the following calculation, which I expect to return 0. However it returns 1 on many systems I have access to:

Ubuntu 16.04 server (wrong)

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-
2017, by Zend Technologies

echo "<?php echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-01 00:00:00')->diff(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-31 23:59:59' ))->format('%m');"|php
1
```

PHP 7.1 from deb.sury.org with Xdebug (wrong)

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2017 
08:26:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright 
(c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans

echo "<?php echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-01 00:00:00')->diff(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-31 23:59:59' ))->format('%m');"|php
1
```

phpfiddle.org

--> returns 0 as expected

The timezones of the date are the same

Comment: I think unless 24 hours next day is not considered. 23:59:59

Comment: Nothing with the question, but: why would you use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` on standard datetime format?

Comment: @Glavic They were just simplified to create the question, they are not created like this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note from `DateInterval::format`:

> The DateInterval::format() method does not recalculate carry over points in time strings nor in date segments. This is expected because it is not possible to overflow values like "32 days" which could be interpreted as anything from "1 month and 4 days" to "1 month and 1 day".

So one has to recalculate carry over points. Below is the [relevant code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#113204) from `DateInterval::format`:

```
class DateIntervalEnhanced extends DateInterval {
    public function recalculate() {
        $from = new DateTime;
        $to = clone $from;
        $to->add($this);
        $diff = $from->diff($to);
        foreach ($diff as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

A utility function:

```
function myFormatter($d1, $d2, $format) {
    $diff = strtotime($d1) - strtotime($d2);
    $df = abs($diff);
    $di = new DateIntervalEnhanced("PT${df}S");
    $di->invert = $diff < 0;
    return $di->recalculate()->format($format);
}

echo myFormatter("2017-12-31 23:59:59", "2017-12-01 00:00:00", "%m");
```

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/xPkVQb)**

**[Link to a post you might wanna read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283682/php-why-does-date-object-diff-on-month-reset-to-0-after-12-months)**

Comment: There are two problems with this solution: Firstly it braks when daylight saving changes. Secondly, the whole purpose in my mind of the DateInterval class is to handle this difference calculation for me at PHP level. I'm more inclined to think its this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480, because I'm in New Zealand Timezone

Comment: @jdog So what is the reason behind posting the question if you knew the problem with carry over points already? Also, what do you mean by my solution breaks? And lastly, what do you mean you want this to handle when DST happens? If DST happens, diff must be inconsistent because same time occurs twice until php allows a pre DST and post DST property.

Comment: Ok, I have done further testing and id not fully understand the limitations of the carryover points. Your solution works with Daylight saving if you don't create the DateIntervalEnhanced object with seconds, but rather with months. I don't see that the month difference must be different if DST occurs in the period, that is exactly what I want to abtsract away