# DateTime diff returning wrong value

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to return the number of days between NOW and some datetime using DateTime object. My dates are:

```
$now = "2018-03-08 14:00:00";
$last = "2018-02-06 20:00:00";
```

And I do it like this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$last_dt = new DateTime($last);
$difference = $last_dt->diff($now);

$difference->format('%d');

$num_of_days = $difference->d;
```

For some weird reason, the value of $num_of_days is 1 (instead of like 30)

Anybody knows why please?

Thank you

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435299/6099347

Comment: You can use `%a` instead of `%d` to get the total number of days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DateInterval::$days` to get the total in days.

`DateInterval::$d` is just the number of days but in "grouping form", i.e. 32 days difference will return 2 for `DateInterval::$d` and `1` for `DateInterval::$m`.

```
$last = "2018-04-10 20:00:00"; 

$now = new DateTime();
$last_dt = new DateTime($last);
$difference = $last_dt->diff($now);

echo "Difference: ".$difference->m." months and ".$difference->d." days, or ".$difference->days." days in total";
```

*Result*

> Difference: 1 months and 2 days, or 33 days in total

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YQVqQ)

You can see more in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props)